# Question about the proof of Zorn's Lemma in Halmos' "Naive Set Theory"

Tags: set-theory

This is about a difficulty I can't seem to get past. In his proof of Zorn's Lemma in the book Naive Set Theory (which can be found for example [here](http://www.owresource.com/misc/mathematics/Set%20Theory/Paul%20R.Halmos%20-%20Naive%20Set%20Theory.pdf) in page 63), after having defined towers as collections satisfying certain properties and letting $\mathscr J_0 = \bigcap \mathscr J $, where J's are all towers, Halmos writes:

> Let us say that a set $ C \in \mathscr J_0 $ is comparable if it is comparable with every set in $ \mathscr J_0 $. [...]Comparable sets surely exist; $ \emptyset $ is one of them.

Then Halmos proceeds to discuss a fixed comparable set $ C $ and the proof is based upon the assumption that $C$ has a proper subset $A$. However, I don't have any idea on how to guarantee the existence of a comparable set besides the empty set. This is my problem: since I can't prove the existence of a comparable set that is not $\emptyset$, I can't allow myself to talk about proper subsets, because if the only comparable set is $\emptyset$ then the discussion of proper subsets is pointless. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** My question is: can someone show me a comparable set that is not empty?

Comment: A comparable set.. *where* ? For example, if we have a collection of sets closed under union, then the union of all the sets is comparable as *any* set there is contained in it...

Comment: Well, $g(\emptyset)$ is nonempty, in $\mathscr{J}_0$, and comparable.

Comment: Whenever you need the axiom of choice it tends to be difficult to actually write down anything concrete. This is why the discussion about whether we should allow it or not exists.

Comment: Someone should mention that Halmos's proof is a rather unpleasant one. He decided not to cover ordinals properly in his book, which meant he couldn't give the easy proof of Zorn via transfinite recursion. So if you're having trouble with his treatment, be aware there are others out there.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: why is $g(\emptyset)$ comparable? It's a singleton, why for instance can we not have any other singleton not equal to $g(\emptyset)$? I believe we have to show that such a singleton does not belong to all $\mathscr J$'s (i.e. there is a tower not containing it) and therefore does not belong to $\mathscr J$, is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Halmos's proof eventually shows that every element in $\mathscr{J}_0$ is comparable, and this includes for example $g(\emptyset)$. But the assumption that a proper subset exists is not needed for the step in question. In that case, the sub-result holds vacuously.

Comment: How come it's not needed? He actually arrives at the contradiction through the sentence "[...]proper subset of a proper subset[...]", doesn't he?

Comment: Clearly, $g(A)\subseteq C$ for all proper subsets $A$ of $C$ if there are no proper subsets of $C$.

Comment: well thanks, there's my tick! :3